restrict requests to storage account container based on blob name via request header using APIM policy
I wish to connect an an api in Azure API manangement to a storage account container. Within this storage account I wish for the api to only be able to access a specific top-level directory in the container ("myfolder"). I am attempting to implement this using an inbound processing policy, but I'm struggling with finding the relevant documentation.
I imagine this involves triggering a 403 back to the user based on either a string variable containing the relevant header containing the blob name, or based on a boolean based on whether i get a regex match with '^myfolder' on the blob name header value. Alternatively, if the previous is not possible, modifying the request such that it fails.
Other possible solutions I could see are using check-header but where the allowed values is a check against its regex value, or using validate-headers, but I haven't figured it out yet
Any pointers to a possible solution would be appreciated

Can you please share the steps and the policy, you have tried so far and also share the error message you are getting while doing so

You can do something like below using Regex
<inbound>
    <base />
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-ms-blob-name", ""), @"^myfolder"))">
            <!-- Allow the request to proceed -->
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <return-response>
                <set-status code="403" reason="Forbidden" />
                <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                    <value>application/json</value>
                </set-header>
                <set-body>
                    {
                        "error": "Access to the requested resource is forbidden. You can only access blobs within the 'myfolder' directory."
                    }
                </set-body>
            </return-response>
        </otherwise>
    </choose>
</inbound>

OR like this
<inbound>
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("x-ms-blob-name", "").StartsWith("myfolder"))">
        <!-- Allow the request to proceed -->
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="403" reason="Forbidden" />
            <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                <value>application/json</value>
            </set-header>
            <set-body>
                {
                    "error": "Access to the requested resource is forbidden. You can only access blobs within the 'myfolder' directory."
                }
            </set-body>
        </return-response>
    </otherwise>
</choose>

